# CordovaからEXIF情報が取得できない。

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, exif

Cordova(Ver.5.2.0)からcordova-plugin-camera経由で取得した
image/jpegのEXIF情報を取得したいと思っております。

ググったところ、[「cordova-exif」](https://github.com/guilhermefarias/cordova-exif)を見つけ、JSをLoadした上で
下記の実装をしております。

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);

function onSuccess(imageURI){
    CordovaExif.readData(imageURI, function(exifObject) {
        alert(exifObject);
    });
}
```

また、iOS8での検証前に「config.xml」に下記設定を行っております。

```
<preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="true" />
```

上記の状態でシミュレータおよび実機で動作確認したところ、alertダイアログが
表示しません。もしかして、EXIF情報の有無が原因がと思い、EXIF情報がある
jpegファイルでも確認しましたが、それでもだめでした。

何か新たな設定が必要なのでしょうか？
もし解決方法がご存知でしたらご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Comment: 追加情報です。

<preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="true" />
を設定してビルドし、写真撮影したのちにアプリが落ちます。
これは上記の現象と関連があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

少し確認をさせて下さい。

1. ソースのインポートはしていますか?

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-exif.js"></script>
   ```
2. `Cordova Exif`が必要としているプラグインはインストールしていますでしょうか??

   ```
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
   ```
3. `onSuccess`メソッド自体が呼び出されていないなんてことはありませんか?
   (onFailなんてことは。。。)

   ```
   function onSuccess(imageURI){
       console.log("func onSuccess"); // Log
       CordovaExif.readData(imageURI, function(exifObject) {
           alert(exifObject);
       });
   }
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
   ```

Comment: 上記の確認について回答します。

1.インポートしています。
2.プラグインは実装済みです。
3.onSuccessメソッドは呼び出しています。(デバッグで確認済み)

Comment: `imageURI`のパスは相対パスですか?`cordova-exif.js`内で使用している`resolveLocalFileSystemURL()`が気になっています。
[exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js)というのもありますがこちらのほうが情報量が多く使えそうな感じです。

Answer (score 0):

コールバック関数の中で、JavaScript の alert() を使用すると、問題が生じる場合があるようです。
https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_3.5/camera/